# How to Change 'Constraint Layout View' to 'Relative Layout View'

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Iam trying to change from Constraint Layout view to Relative Layout View in android stdio.

I have tried changing and edit the Template files from @ROOTTAG TO Relative layout but nothing seems to be changed

```
<android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout 
xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `<RelativeLayout` instead of `<android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout`

Comment: tried that too still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55784243/edit) some explanation to your answer